# need a .htacces condition to remove index.php

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect

I need to remove `index.php` from the URL and redirect to `http://www.example.com/`.

passing URL is

```
http://www.example.com/index.php
```

if the URL is

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/about-us
```

I need to redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/about-us
```

My .htaccess Code

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Please do share your htaccess file in your question, thank you.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    #redirect http://www.example.com/index.php/about-us to http://www.example.com/about-us But not work for http://www.example.com/index.php to http://www.example.com/
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]
</IfModule>

Comment: @JebinJoseph Please edit your question to add the code block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```